# Click delete button in rows by class name

Tags: jquery

I've an HTML table data on a webpage. Now, the table displays a red border (class .p_AFError)
around the rows with error data. I need to click on delete button on each row to remove those rows.

Now, I tried

`jQuery('.p_AFError ').select()` over console, gives me below result.

```
n.fn.init(3) [div#r1:1:r1:1:m1.p_AFError.is-hidden.af_messages, **span#r1:1:r1:1:r1:0:t1:8**:it1.p_AFError.inp.table-inp.af_inputText, **span#r1:1:r1:1:r1:0:t1:12**:it1.p_AFError.inp.table-inp.af_inputText, prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: '.p_AFError ']
```

Can someone suggest how to I extract the values `span#r1:1:r1:1:r1:0:t1:8` and `span#r1:1:r1:1:r1:0:t1:12`.

8,12 indicates the row.

Comment: `.select()` is a shorthand for creating a select event listener, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: jquery *chains* return values, so the return from `$("p").select()` is the same as the return from `$("p")` - ie a jquery collection containing elements from your selector - that's what `n.fn.init` is telling you - it's a jquery collection.   Don't try to use the toString rendering of it.

Comment: Exactly which elements have p_AFError applied to them?  The `<tr>`s?  Looks like it might be a `span` - but where in relation to your buttons is that span?  Might need to include some HTML.